# Event for network drive change/connected/disconnected in .Net Core in Windows

Tags: c#, .net-core, network-drive

**The scenario:**

I've got an application that the data is based on a network drive.
I need to refresh the data on every change of network drive or if the drive is disconnected/connected.

**The question:**

Is there any event for network drive change/connected/disconnected in Windows?

**Solutions that I checked and doesn't work:**

1. Using `FileSystemWatcher`
2. Using `WMI` and `Win32_VolumeChangeEvent` for detecting drive change is not working for network drives.
3. I can use `WMI` and get all the network drive on every X time by using the searcher:

   ```
   var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_MappedLogicalDisk");
   ```

   But this approach is less efficient and I prefer to find an event for a change.

Comment: Why doesn't FileSystemWatcher work? is there something special with the server you connect to?

Comment: @rene The FileSystemWatcher doesn't watch for these kinds of changes. Let say I want to track the change of I:\ drive. If the drive disconnect or map changed, no event raised.